# Google Analytics. Can we get the analytic data for less than one day?

Tags: java, google-analytics, socket-timeout-exception

I am using Google analytics and my code was working fine so far. When I'm requesting for the data (since I am getting the data for each day) I pass the same value for start and end date. But in a particular case I received "Read Timeout" error. I assume the issue is because of big data returned by the query (what do you think?).

I came up with this solution to shrink the time frame and process the data chunk by chunk. But is it possible? can we collect the data for less than one day?

here is how I create the query

```
Analytics.Data.Ga.Get query = service.data().ga().get(profile.getTableId(), asGoogleFormat(requestDate), asGoogleFormat(requestDate),"ga:sessions");
```

which google format is "yyyy-MM-dd".

I get an error when trying to execute the query saying "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out"

Thanks!